# How to create akka actor with different path?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

If create an actor (without name) it will live in path `akka.tcp://system@192.168.1.2:2552/user/$a#-576914160`. If it possible to create an actor directly in `myGpurp` sub path? E.g. result actor path will be `akka.tcp://system@192.168.1.2:2552/user/myGpurp/$a#-576914160`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an actor named `myGpurp` and then ask that actor to create a child. That is the only way to have the path you want.

Answer (score 4):

First you have to create named actor myGpurp:

```
val myGpurp: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[myGpurp]),"myGpurp")
```

In MyGpurp you can create anonymous or named actor:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}

class MyGpurp extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case m: Any =>
      val child: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]))
      child ! "Message"
  }
}
```

Path to your SomeActor will be like akka.tcp://system@192.168.1.2:2552/user/myGpurp/$a#-576914160